# Android studio.How can i access files in data/data/com.xxx.xxx

Tags: java, android, android-studio, permissions

I want to see whether a file is in data/data/com.xxx.xxx or not. Do i need some permissions to visit the dir?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only access to /data/data/com.xxx.xxx if com.xxx.xxx is your package name or application contains the package name that shared with your applications, when you can be able to access file in the path.
Docs [link](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/).